# The best way to remove a key from react component's state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state, react-state

I am using a react class component, which holds a state, with (lets say..) a lot of key-value pairs stored into it.
Upon user action (button press/toggle), I need to REMOVE / ADD a new key-value pair to the component's state. Adding one is relatively easy, but pulling out a key-value pair from the state can be done in several different ways, so I was wondering which one is best, most readable, most performant and most preferred by the ReactJS audience..

1) Option 1:

```
onRemove = key => {
    const newState = this.state;
    delete newState[key] // Interacts directly with the state, which might not be a good practice, or expended behaviour?
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

2) Option 2:

```
onRemove = key => {
    const {[key]: removedKey, ...newState} = this.state; // Defines two new variables, one of which won't be used - "removedKey";
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

There might be more ways to do it, and I am wondering which might be the best one, that can be used in any circumstance, no matter how 'big' the state gets...

Please share your thoughts based on your work experience with React & State management!

Thanks!

Comment: This question *appears* subjective on the face of it, but isn't really. Option 1 isn't an option at all, it breaks one of the React rules: Never modify state directly.

Comment: I get `Cannot find name 'key'.ts(2304)` for Option2 in typescript.

Answer (score 2):

When I do something like this, I generally do a modified version of your "Option 1." As you currently have it, Option 1 mutates the state object, which you shouldn't do. Instead, create a shallow copy of state and then delete the key.

```
onRemove = key => {
    const newState = {...this.state};
    delete newState[key];
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

The reason I like this way over your Option 2 is subjective--It's *very* readable to me. Make a copy, `delete` a key. Simple and to the point.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable alternative. Deleting a property from an object used to hurt its property lookup performance (for those 0.0001% of times it mattered), but I don't think that's true anymore (or at least not *as* true).

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 isn't an option. You [can't directly modify state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) in React.

Option 2 is fairly standard practice.

A third (to my mind lesser) option is to remove the property after cloning the object, but deleting properties from objects isn't what JavaScript engines optimize for, so I don't see any advantage to it over Option 2.

Comment: Well option two is the one I use but I see 2 not-so-nice things within it: adds additional two variables, adds a variable which is unused and linter is warning...